# How to make passwd, group and shadow file persistent in docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-volume

I want to persist user and its credentials which are created inside Docker. My scenario is like this: every time when a new build comes I have to remove the running container and relaunch the container with that new image. I had tried to use bind mount of `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` but it is not working. I have also tried to create docker volume and mount `/etc` in that but no luck.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] showing when and why these files are changed after the container is started?  Especially `/etc/shadow` is almost never used in Docker, since the single process containers run typically isn't a login-type process.